# JSLint error from ternary statement

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'd like to know why ternary conditional-statements like these:

`on_actu.boolean ? IMG1 = "on-actu.png" : IMG1 = "off-actu.png";`

give me the following JSLint error :

> expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Comment: `IMG1 = on_actu.boolean ?  "on-actu.png" :  "off-actu.png";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the ternary operator wrong.

```
ValueToAssign = BooleanConditional ? valueOne : valueTwo;
```

More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 1):

On the left you can specify variable to which you are setting value, and on the right the actual value;

```
IMG1 = on_actu.boolean ? "on-actu.png" : "off-actu.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this example

```
var IMG1 = on_actu.boolean ? "on-actu.png" : "off-actu.png";
```

Regars